# Cannot implicitly convert type class to class

Tags: c#

I had the same problem as this SO question : [TextBox, Button and ListBox in a ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632713/textbox-button-and-listbox-in-a-listbox)

So i took the answer of @Andy but it gives me trouble :

```
private void ButtonAddNewTask_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
                IssueView curIssue = (Issue)btn.DataContext;
                if (curIssue != null)
                {
                    curIssue.Issue.Comments.Add(new Comment()
                    {
                        Commentary = curIssue.NewCommentName
                    });
                }
}
```

I wonder if it is my mistake and i didn't well adapt his answer to my code, if the post is too old or if @Andy forget something and i can't get what.

**Edit** My classes and adapted Button click event

```
public sealed class Issue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Comment> comments =
    new ObservableCollection<Comment>();
    public IList<Comment> Comments
    {
        get { return comments; }
    }
}

public sealed class Comment
{

    // string AssociatedIssue { get; set; }
    public string Commentary { get; set; }
}

class IssueView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Issue Issue { get; set; }

    private string newCommentName = string.Empty;

    public string NewCommentName
    {
        get { return newCommentName; }
        set
        {
            newCommentName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("NewCommentName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Here `Project` and `ProjectView` seems to be specific classes (interfaces?) for the code of that questioner. You should adapt that to your clases

Comment: What are the types you are working with

Comment: Here are the classes i'm working with, these are basically the same as the linked SO question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Types at the beginning and end of this statement should be the same
ProjectView curProject = btn.DataContext as ProjectView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a ProjectView in a ProjectView variable (rather than a Project).

```
 ProjectView curProject = (btn.DataContext as ProjectView);
```

If that DataContext can never be converted to a ProjectView, then curProject will always be null.

Answer (score -2):

Could you try it like this?:

```
private void ButtonAddNewTask_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Button btn = (Button)sender;
ProjectView curProject = (Project) btn.DataContext;
if(null != curProject)
    {
    curProject.Project.Tasks.Add(new Task()
        {
        Name = curProject.NewTaskName
        });
    }
}
```

How are you trying to convert a Project to an ProjectView. It seems like, that they are two different classes without any inheritance.

Comment: @Babuh Sorry, i was editing my answer, could you please read the last sentences and provide some information about the classes?

Comment: Well, before downvoting me, you could give some more information, if you want someone to help you.

Comment: i 'm not the one downvoting you =) i update my question to provide my classes

Comment: @Babuh How do you want to parse the "Issue" into an "IssueView". Those are two different objects.

Comment: ok thank you =) i thought that was possible because @Andy did it but it must be a mistake !

Comment: @Babuh, as you can see in Andy's Answer he parsed an Object like this "Project proj = button.DataContext as Project;". So he is parsing from "Project" to "Project" but not from one object into another.