# In wpf How to bind dynamic textbox in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I created a Listbox in XAML page. when I click the listbox double click it will turns the listitem to textbox.I want to modify the text using textbox. when click the enter button, the textbox turns to listitem.

```
 private void lstbxindex_MouseDoubleClick(object sender,MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox txtNumber = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();
        txtNumber.Name = "ProjectlistItems";

        tb.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(tb_KeyDown);

        }
   private static void tb_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            txtNumber.Text = lstbxindex.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lstbxindex.Items.Add(txtNumber);

        }
```

Comment: And have you tried anything?

Comment: No, I simply created the listbox in XAML page.

Comment: hahaha @LogeswariJegatheesan you are such a champ...

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly talking about making ListBoxItem Editable. You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632713/textbox-button-and-listbox-in-a-listbox)

Or just search for "Editable Listbox WPF" for better results.